# spring-social-linkedin only retrieved two current positions and no past positions

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

I'm using spring-social-linkedin 1.0.1.RELEASE and when I iterate through positions after calling:

```
.getUserProfileFull().getPositions()
```

it only returns up to two current positions and no past positions.

Is there a way to configure it to bring back all past and present positions?

Answer (score 0):

Per LinkedIn's API documentation at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields,  "Only current positions are available for people other than the authenticated member." There doesn't appear to be any way to configure it otherwise.

Comment: What's the definition of 'authenticated member'? I think that might be where my confusion lies.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve positions as the authenticated member and I'm still only getting the current positions (despite what the documentation says). Can anyone confirm that they _CAN_ retrieve the full position history?